# javascript Extracting an element from HTML - Keeping parent/child structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Having the following html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="first">
            1
            <div class="first-first">
                <p>1.1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="first-second">
                <p>1.2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            2
            <div class="second-first">
                <p>2.1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="second-second">
                <p>2.2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How could I extract an element from the HTML keeping his parent-child structure? e.g. if I want to extract the class '**second-first**', I will have a html object that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="second">
            2
            <div class="second-first">
                <p>2.1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So **#first** and **.second-second** will be removed.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3G7Dk/1/)

I've tried different approaches but with no success at all, also if someone knows how to do that with a time complexity less than O(n^2) would be great to know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kmn8G/1/

Comment: Close but I don't want to remove the content, only extracts in another object. I've tried to clone the HTML, instead of removing it, but it doesn't work!